# How to scale a canvas image larger and smaller in a continuous loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, canvas

I created a cloud shape in canvas, and I'm wondering how I can scale the shape back and forth between larger and smaller. Like I want the cloud to get bigger, than smaller, then bigger then smaller, etc.

I was able to be able to move a separate canvas image up and down using a when-then method, but I don't think that method will work by increasing the canvas size because the actual image stays to scale.

Here is my canvas code:

```
<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById('hardware-cloud');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

// begin cloud shape-Hardware
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(180, 80);
context.bezierCurveTo(150, 132, 143, 165, 203, 154);
context.bezierCurveTo(203, 154, 180, 200, 260, 175);
context.bezierCurveTo(297, 231, 352, 198, 344, 185);
context.bezierCurveTo(344, 185, 372, 215, 374, 175);
context.bezierCurveTo(473, 165, 462, 132, 429, 110);
context.bezierCurveTo(473, 44, 407, 33, 374, 55);
context.bezierCurveTo(352, 10, 275, 22, 275, 55);
context.bezierCurveTo(210, 20, 165, 22, 180, 80);

// complete cloud shape-Hardware
context.closePath();
context.lineWidth = 5;
context.strokeStyle = 'navy';
context.stroke();
context.fillStyle = 'white';
context.fill();

//font inside hardware cloud
context.beginPath();
context.font = 'bold 15pt Calibri';
context.textAlign = 'center';
context.fillStyle ="navy";  // <-- Text colour here
context.fillText('Why not the electronic store?', 300, 120);
context.lineWidth = 2;
context.strokeStyle = 'grey';
context.stroke();
context.closePath();

//top  hardware circle
context.beginPath();
context.arc(380, 220, 13, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
context.lineWidth = 5;
context.strokeStyle = 'navy';
context.stroke();
context.fillStyle = 'white';
context.fill();
context.closePath();

//middle hardware circle
context.beginPath();
context.arc(398, 253, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
context.lineWidth = 5;
context.strokeStyle = 'navy';
context.stroke();
context.fillStyle = 'white';
context.fill();
context.closePath();

//bottom hardware circle
context.beginPath();
context.arc(425, 273, 7, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
context.lineWidth = 5;
context.strokeStyle = 'navy';
context.stroke();
context.fillStyle = 'white';
context.fill();
context.closePath();
</script>
```

And here is my attempt at the jQuery. The first part of it is to get the div region to slide into view. The second part is an attempt to scale up and down.:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#hardware').hide();
$('#hardware').show("slide", {direction: "left"}, 400 );

ani();
function ani(){
$.when(
$('#hardware-cloud').effect({
scale: "120"},700),
   $('#hardware-cloud').effect({
scale: "100"},700)
.then(ani));}
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use scale and translate to change the size of the shape.

All transforms works for the *next* drawn shape and doesn't affect already drawn shapes.

So for it to work you'll need to clear the canvas, transform and then redraw the shape.

For example, re-factor the code so that you can call `shape()` to draw the cloud, then:

- Clear canvas `ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);`
- Apply scale `ctx.scale(scaleX, scaleY);`
- Optionally translate the shape using `ctx.translate(deltaX, deltaY);`
- Redraw shape `shape();`
- Repeat using for example `requestAnimationFrame()` in a loop.

Scale value is 1 = 1:1, 0.5 = half etc. Just remember these transforms are accumulative (you can use `setTransform()` to set absolute transforms each time).

**Update**

Here is one way you can do this:

```
var maxScale = 1,  // for demo, this represents "max"
    current = 0,   // angle (in radians) used to scale smoother
    step = 0.02,   // speed
    pi2 = Math.PI; // cached value

// main loop clears, transforms and redraws shape
function loop() {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    transform();
    drawShape();
    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}
requestAnimationFrame(loop);

// set scale based on rotation
function transform() {
    current += step;
    current %= pi2;

    // just play around with different combinations here
    var s = (maxScale * Math.abs(Math.sin(current))) / maxScale + 0.5;

    // set absolute scale
    context.setTransform(s, 0, 0, s, 0, 0);
}

// wrap shape calls in a function so it can be reused
function drawShape() {
    // begin cloud shape-Hardware
    context.beginPath();
    ... rest goes here...
```

### [Online demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/TGP5T/1/)

In addition you can use `translate()` to re-position the shape linked to the rotation value.

Hope this helps!

Comment: ahhh im getting stuck. can you do a jsfiddle for me please? Do I redraw the shape like this?

    function redraw(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById("hardware-cloud");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.scale(0.9,0.9);

Comment: I'm calling the entire canvas by this:

function callshape(){

Comment: @user3386635 please set up a fiddle with what you got so far then we can use that as a basis.